# Why would "Generate Getters and Setters..." shortcut be disabled in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, shortcut, getter-setter

I am using Eclipse 4.9.0.

I have a whole bunch of fields for which I want to generate getters and setters in a certain file. However, the option does not appear in the context menu (alt+shift+S), and if I go to menu bar Source > Generate Getters and Setters... , it is grayed out (disabled).

In another file in the same project the option is available, so it is not a problem with my IDE.

To make things stranger, when I hover over the variables and the suggestions to address that these variables are not used come up, one of them is the option to create getters and setters, and selecting that *does* bring up the dialogue, but only for one field at a time. It does successfully create getters and setters that way.

Sample code:

```
@Entity
public class sampleClass extends anotherClass {

  @Id
  private String sampleVar1;
  private String sampleVar2;
  private Date sampleVar3;
  private int sampleVar4;
```

What would cause the getter/setter generation to be disabled?

Comment: Is the file editable and not derived?

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: @MWB there is no real code - it's just a list of declarations of class variables to be called from elsewhere in the package.

Comment: Not quite on topic, but have you considered using the Lombok library to avoid writing this kind of boilerplate code in the first place?

Comment: Do you get the same behavior if you remove the `@Id` annotation?

Comment: @Laf Yeah, and if I remove `@Entity`

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue in Eclipse 2019-03 (4.11) and cannot found a bug report for this. Do you have third-party plug-ins installed?

Comment: @howlger just findbugs and gson.

Comment: @Y  e  z Eclipse 4.9 is outdated and is no longer maintained. Can you reproduce this issue in Eclipse 2019-03 (4.11) in a _Hello World_ project? By the way, the FindBugs plug-in is also outdated and have been replaced by [SpotBugs](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spotbugs-eclipse-plugin).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your cursor placement. I guess you are not placing your mouse pointer in the right place. If you place your cursor anywhere outside the class parenthesis then you may not be able to generate it. Make sure your mouse pointer is next to your variable assignment. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I tried that. I tried having the cursor on a variable name, tried highlighting a variable, highlighting the entire line, and none of it made a difference.